# Add Missing Vendor specifics in Web Essentials 2017

Tags: sass, visual-studio-2017, web-essentials

I've just recently installed Visual Studio 2017 and Web Essentials 2017. Now i cant find the option to add missing vendor specifics in my scss files. Previously was using VS 2013 with Web Essentials 2013 and it had the option.

Any Ideas how i can get this back?

Answer (score 1):

From the same creator of WebEssential you can download AutoPrefixer.

I hope in the future will be included in WebEssential, but for the moment you can download it separately.

**CSS AutoPrefixer (by Mads Kristensen for Visual Studio 2015 and 2017)**
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.CSSAutoPrefixer

Cheers